# Introduce a review ban timer instead of vague default message

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, review-suspension

I recently landed myself in review jail for reasons and I noticed that this ban lasted longer than the last time that I was banned. After some investigation I found out that each ban is longer than the last if it occurs within a given interval. I have no problem with this policy.

Anyway I'd like to suggest a timer in hours or days that would appear in the review tooltip in the SO toolbar.

So instead of just getting this message;

> There are no review queues available to you.

You'd see something like this;

> There are no review queues available to you. Check back in 89 days.

Also if the `89 days` had a embedded link to a page with the different types of review bans and how many you as a user have 'earned' kind of like when you click on the [badges button](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) on the dashboard.

I think something like that would help to reinforce the idea that you are being punished but this punishment will come to an end with time. The current system is a little kafka-esque IMO.

Comment: Pro-tip: Middle click / ctrl+click on the review menu and it takes you to the review page which (IIRC) has a message with the remaining days in it.

Comment: Moderators have that view hidden behind a couple links, but it's not shown to users in the spirit of holding no grudges. The time should definitely be shown in the popover, though - or at least a link to the review homepage where you can see it.